# Does general linear model includes interaction?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, multiple-regression, linear-model

From the general linear model, we know the following :

$E(\pmb{\hat{\beta}}) = E((\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y}) $

and

$Var(\pmb{\hat{\beta}})  = \sigma^2(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1}$.

Does that hold true when interaction effects are included, that is $\mathbf{X}$ contains variables and the products of each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. $\mathbf X$ is agnostic about what goes into it; the columns can represent (1) individual numeric covariates (or nonlinear transformations thereof), (2) dummy variables associated with categorical variables, (3) elements of a computed basis (such as a spline or orthogonal polynomial), or (4) elements of the interactions (== products of columns) of any of the above.

Comment: Thank you. Would the convergence varies depending on the distributions?

Comment: The general linear model typically assumes a Gaussian conditional distribution. Other conditional distributions would suggest that you're working with a *generalized* (rather than *general*) linear model, at which points questions about convergence etc. could get much more complicated.

Comment: @POC convergence of what, exactly?

Comment: The composition of X does affect convergence of the fitting algorithm in generalized linear models, because of collinearity. Note that this is not the same as convergence of a sample to any distribution, and also doesn't quite apply to the formula you posted, because in that case you have to worry that $X^TX$ is invertible (there is no multi-step fitting algorithm, and thus no convergence or divergence).

Comment: Maybe the word i'm looking for is *efficient* rather than convergence @Glen_b. Would the efficiency be the same for all $\mathbf{B}$ if the distributions in $\mathbf{X}$ are different (like the interaction terms)? Maybe, it should be a question altogether.

Comment: Andrew Gelman points out that the power to detect an interaction is usually much lower than that to detect main effects: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/03/15/need16/  ... maybe that's what you're after?